# Send text to ConEmu tab

Tags: conemu

I want to send text to a specific (not active) ConEmu tab.
Sending to active tab with works fine.

```
ConEmuC -GuiMacro:0 print("cd /tmp")
```

But when I try to use tab number as specified in https://conemu.github.io/en/GuiMacro.html#Command_line it silently fails:

```
ConEmuC -GuiMacro:T1 print("cd /tmp")
```

I'm aware that before print() the tab can be activated with Tab function but this causes tab "flicker" which I'm interested to avoid since text is being sent asynchronously from external program.

Comment: Do you try to run `ConEmuC` from one of the ConEmu tabs or somewhere outside of ConEmu window?

Comment: From outside (cmd window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tried the following syntax and it worked for me:

```
ConEmuC -GuiMacro:0:T2 print: test
```

I guess ConEmuC expects you to tell it which application it should work on, and then which tab it should work on. That takes 2 parameters. `0` tells it to work on the first ConEmu instance it finds, then `T2` tells it to work on the 2nd tab. ConEmu's tab numbering starts at 1 I believe. I successfully sent test to the 2nd inactive tab.
[image]